# I don't have batch entry of contributions - why?

Tags: contributions

I don't seem to have the "batch entry" feature in our Civi database.  When I go to the Contributions drop down where it should appear, it's not there.  Does this mean I'm running a downlevel version of Civi and if so, how do I find out what version I have?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the version of CiviCRM at the bottom of any CiviCRM page

it will say 
Powered by **CiviCRM 4.6.5.** CiviCRM is openly available under the GNU AGPL License.

Please try to install the latest version of Civicrm which has the feature